# Attempt to store into an expression: Structure reference

Tags: list, reference, expression, structure, idl

I've got the following problem in IDL language (I have different size arrays in a list of structures and I try to change the values in those arrays, but it gives me the error called "Attempt to store into an expression: Structure reference.").
Example code:

```
a = list()
a.add,{a: 1, b: findgen(10)}
a.add,{a: 2, b: findgen(20)}
a[0].b[5] = 2
% Attempt to store into an expression: Structure reference.
```

Could anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround for this? I haven't found any useful tips for this situation so far.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I use IDL 8.2.1

EDIT2: It does not work with IDL 8.4 either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an IDL novice myself, but I think what is happening when you access a structure in a list, is that the list is returning a copy of the structure.  When this copy is on the left-hand side, it is a temporary, and IDL is preventing the assignment to a temporary.

Try this:

```
a = list()
a.add,{a: 1, b: findgen(10)}
a.add,{a: 2, b: findgen(20)}
c = a[0]
c.b[5] = 2
a[0] = c
print, a[0].b
0.000000      1.00000      2.00000      3.00000      4.00000      2.00000      6.00000      7.00000      8.00000      9.00000
```

The problem with this is that it's cumbersome and expensive to make a copy of the struct.  Maybe there is a better way to handle this?

Edit: perhaps this Google discussion will provide some insight:

[Modifying Arrays and Structures in HASH's (hint: you can't)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/ymba1dt4qJc)

Comment: So no solution. :( Thanks, anyway.